# How to Catch the Unhandled exception of preprocess step of "SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild" exe using c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Hi all I'm trying to create a VS2015 plugin which will do the Sonarqube analysis as a single step (instead of current [three steps](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900)) because first step only has the configuration part remaining two steps are common for all the .Net solution.

**Software details:**

- SonarQube v5.6.6
- SonarC# v6.0
- SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild v3.0.0
- Sonar fxcop v1.0

**Scenario:**

- In my case am calling the pre-process step
  (%cd%\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"key" /v:"version"
  /n:"Name") using "**System.Diagnostics.Process**" in simple trycatch block. its works fine.
- In the System.Diagnostics.Process exit code returns zero & no exception are catched, when pre-process step fails (due to "unhandled exception" or unable to delete some file or some other issue) SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe log a message as "**Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1**" in the logger.

So please suggest me to handle (or catch) the exception in System.Diagnostics.Process or should i use any other approach to handle this case.

Comment: According to the error log, it seems like there is an exception in your code. You can try to use Debug with Exception settings to catch this exception instead of SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks Leo, please refer the [code](https://github.com/vival30/Sample/blob/master/ExcecuteCmdinCL) which i used to execute commands in the **System.Diagnostics.Process**